# How to Integrate GLUU & ADFS

Tags: spring-security, saml-2.0, adfs, gluu

I have a working setup of `GLUU` [referece](https://gluu.org/) with customized login and `ADFS`. Both are working fine individually,
Now I would need to change the primary authentication of ADFS with GLUU, So that the authentication will happen at the GLUU.

Is there any reference to integrate ADFS with GLUU

Ideally ADFS should act a service provider and GLUU will act as a Identity provider. Can someone please help or suggest how to proceed on this.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this as per [these guidelines](https://gluu.org/docs/ce/admin-guide/saml/).

Essentially, import the ADFS metadata into GLUU.

Then create an ADFS CP and import the GLUU metadata.

This uses SAML so you need a claims rule for NameID.

Use a claims Transform rule to convert e.g. email to NameID format email.

Then configure e.g. email as the NameID type in GLUU.